# How to get top N% of data by group in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We have a table where we want to divide the data in train, test and split. It should split like per type top 20% data in validation, next 20% data in test and remaining 60% in train.
For example, we have 10 rows of type 6069. We have to split like 20% rows i.e., first 2 rows of type 6069 in validation, 2 rows in test and 6 rows in train.
When there are odd count of types then we can round up and split accordingly.

Is there a way we can do that in SQL?

| text | type |
| --- | --- |
| 6131484974365 | 6069 |
| 6219352421449 | 6069 |
| 6088998688036 | 6069 |
| 6090518587777 | 6069 |
| 6093295054628 | 6069 |
| 6131484976666 | 6069 |
| 6219352421449 | 6069 |
| 608899867190 | 6069 |
| 6090518587635 | 6069 |
| 6093295054628 | 6069 |
| 6055705684714 | 5012 |
| 6064031434087 | 5012 |
| 6066932173638 | 5012 |
| 6058029881152 | 5012 |
| 6131484974333 | 6070 |
| 6219352421398 | 6070 |
| 6088998680253 | 6070 |
| 6090518587333 | 6022 |
| 6093295052838 | 6022 |
| 6055705682323 | 6022 |
| 6064031431111 | 6022 |
| 6066932173600 | 6022 |
| 6058029881444 | 6022 |

Expected output:

| text | type | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6131484974365 | 6069 | test |
| 6219352421449 | 6069 | test |
| 6088998688036 | 6069 | validation |
| 6090518587777 | 6069 | validation |
| 6093295054628 | 6069 | train |
| 6131484976666 | 6069 | train |
| 6219352421449 | 6069 | train |
| 608899867190 | 6069 | train |
| 6090518587635 | 6069 | train |
| 6093295054628 | 6069 | train |
| 6055705684714 | 5012 | test |
| 6064031434087 | 5012 | validation |
| 6066932173638 | 5012 | train |
| 6058029881152 | 5012 | train |
| 6131484974333 | 6070 | test |
| 6219352421398 | 6070 | validation |
| 6088998680253 | 6070 | train |
| 6090518587333 | 6022 | test |
| 6093295052838 | 6022 | validation |
| 6055705682323 | 6022 | train |
| 6064031431111 | 6022 | train |
| 6066932173600 | 6022 | train |
| 6058029881444 | 6022 | train |

Comment: give examples of what sizes the different groups are when the count is not a multiple of 5, say if 6069 had 11, 12, 13, or 14 rows.

Comment: you also say "top 20%" but don't explain top according to what.  once you know how many rows should be in each of the three groups, how do you want to determine which group an individual row is in.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the 6069 using where clause with  keyword TOP and PERCENT in the select clause

```
SELECT TOP (10) PERCENT
text
FROM TABLE
WHERE type = 6069
```

And then select the TOP (20) PERCENT and remove the TOP (10) PERCENT by using DISTINCT (assuming they are different) which leave out the middle 10%.

Or you can do ROW_NUMBER over PARTITION BY type. And then select ROW_NUMBER from certain range in the where clause.

Comment: mysql does not support TOP like this

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want 20/20/60 percent data of each type. 'WHERE type = 6069' will give only single type.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this query

```
type_count AS
     (SELECT 
            type, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM data
      GROUP BY type)
SELECT d.text, d.type,
       CASE
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.type) <= CEIL(0.2*c.total) THEN 'test' 
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.type) <= CEIL(0.4*c.total) THEN 'validation'
         ELSE 'train'
       END AS data_type 
FROM  data d INNER JOIN type_count c ON d.type = c.type
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lUVW8VYz)

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer. But this is not giving me correct answer when I apply to my query. It is copying the text as many times as count of each label

Comment: @Shtutz Please update your question to include your expectation output

Comment: Added as requested. :)

Comment: So it doesn't split exactly to 20%/20%/60% per each group. The distribution per each group will depend on total data per each group?

Comment: Yes. The distribution per each group will depend on total data per each group.

Comment: I've edited my query to include at least 1 record per each group.  You could check the demo at this link: https://dbfiddle.uk/lUVW8VYz